# Python FLASK get all value from bootstrap select (multiple)

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, select, flask

I am using the flask web framework to get the values of select.

HTML,

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-7">
       <label for="ex2">Add User To Groups:</label>
       <select id = "usergroups" name = "usergroups" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
        {% for i in range(record_num): %}
        <option value="{{ name[i] }}" data-tokens="{{ name[i] }}">{{ name[i] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
       </select>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Python Code,

```
groupnames = request.form.getlist['usergroups']
```

Output on the browser
I get an internal server error.

AM I MISSING SOMETHING HERE ?

Comment: It doesn't look like record_num is defined...in which case, when the server tries to run the code, it will crash, generating an internal server error.

Comment: Do you have debug mode on? Did you get a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

`reques.form.getlist` is function,not a dict:)

Try:

```
request.form.getlist('usergroups')
```